# DeleteStaleTemplateCaches stalled tasks

Tags: stalled-tasks

I have a dev site that I'm working on with around 1000 entries - mainly text content. I keep seeing "DeleteStaleTemplateCaches" stalled tasks come up - many times stacking 6-8 sets of similar stuck tasks.

I've read the article about stalled tasks but it seems to say they are the result of using a cache tag. I have no caching of any kind - no cache tags and no caching on the server (that I'm aware of). I'm sometimes able to clear the tasks using Task Manager (after many tries) but they always return.

Is there anything else I should check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any data in your 3 `craft_templatecache*` tables? When a task stalls, do you get a related error message in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` or your web server's error logs?

Comment: Here's what the database shows for those tables: http://jmp.sh/kZ3vdHp

In the logs I see things like this: 
2017/10/27 14:39:53 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting task DeleteStaleTemplateCaches that has a total of 9533 steps.
2017/10/27 14:39:53 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting step 1 of 9533 total steps.
...
2017/10/27 14:39:57 [info] [application] [Forced] Finished task 48 (DeleteStaleTemplateCaches).

Comment: Did the site use the `{% cache %}` tag at some point and was removed later?  There's definitely data in the tables.  You can nuke the data in there safely... it'll just rebuild if the cache tag is in use as needed.

Comment: It's possible that the cache tag was used in the past. I cleared those tables and now everything seems peachy. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Brad Bell who solved this for me. There was data in my craft_templatecache* tables. When I cleared them out the issue went away.